# executing update query in sqlLite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is my the query. Can any one please check is it write or wrong..thanks.. because i am getting nuller pointer exception

```
mydb.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ TABLE + " SET ReferenceNo= '"+ref.getText().toString()+"' , Mobile= '"+mob.getText().toString()+"' where ID= '"+id +"'", null);
```

Comment: Is ID a number? Also, if you are getting Null Pointer Exception, please make sure mydb, ref and mob are not NULL. And, please post the Logs as well.

Comment: Show some more code. As if you are getting the nullpointer exception there must be any of value `mob.getText().toString()` ,`ref.getText().toString()` or `id` can be null. Make sure you have initialized the views and setting values into it.

Comment: Query seems okay as you are not getting SqliteException. There must be problem with variable values.